# HTTP Request works in Postman but not in HTTPIE

Tags: httpie

I'm trying to make a simple http request to https://ip2country.info/ using [httpie](https://httpie.io/docs/cli).

For the life of me I can't get it to work. I'm trying to request to this URL: https://api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8

When I use this in Postman it works perfectly. But in httpie here's my request and response:

Request: `http api.ip2country.info ip==5.6.7.8`
Response: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Screenshots

httpie:
[image]

postman:
[image]

Comment: Can you take screenshots of both postman and httpie? I believe I know the issue but I want to verify the url and headers.

Comment: @KeeganM Yep, just added screenshots

Comment: This has do with the URL schema, it's not sending the requests as HTTPS for some reason and keeps sending a redirect to the exact same url, but with https, which is a trait of nginx when listening on port 80. Im attempting to find a solution right now

Answer (score 1):

**Test Case**

The request, as stands, to `https://api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8` by httpie return a redirect error code, yet works in postman `api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8`.

**Solution**

The request works in postman because postman directly accesses the url with hard-coded query params. Httpie is supposed to be "easier" by allowing a builder interfact on the command line.

The command `http api.ip2country.info ip==5.6.7.8` will essentially build a request to `http://api.ip2country.info?ip=5.6.7.8` which is different then the intended url plugged into postman.

- Intended: `https://api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8`
- Actual:   `http://api.ip2country.info?ip=5.6.7.8`

By directly coding the query params into httpie and changing the scheme to https like `https api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.1`, a response of

```json
{
    "countryCode": "DE",
    "countryCode3": "DEU",
    "countryEmoji": ""  ,
    "countryName": "Germany"
}
```

is retrieved. The only provided query param is a single key IP with no value, which httpie doesn't support in their builder (since it's fairly taboo), and requires it to just be manually appended to the end of the request URL with `?{ip}`

Comment: Ah i see — that makes sense. However, the request still doesn't work in httpie. Here's what I tried: `http api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8` and my response was this: `no matches found: api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8`

Comment: Try using the keyword `https` instead of http. 90% of modern websites require https protocol

Comment: Hmm, I tried this: `https api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8`  and I get the same error: `api.ip2country.info/ip?5.6.7.8`

Comment: What installation method are you using for httpie?

Comment: Im using pip and just tried the online one https://httpie.io/cli/run and got the intended response